# Collection.toArray() java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer,Class> map=new HashMap<Integer,Class>();
        map.put(0,Main.class);
        Class[] classes=(Class[])map.values().toArray();
        for (Class c:classes)
            System.out.println(c.getName());
    }

}
```

I try cast in this line `Class[] classes=(Class[])map.values().toArray();` but get exception.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Class;
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)`

What is problem?

Comment: Also, what's up with the "[L...;" notation for class names?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change:

```
Class[] classes = (Class[]) map.values().toArray();
```

To:

```
Class[] classes = map.values().toArray(new Class[0]);
```

This gives information on which type of array to convert the `Collection` to. Otherwise, it returns an array of type `Object` (and that cannot be cast to an `Class[]`).

---

Quoted from [the API documentation for `Collection.toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29):

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection; the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array. ...
>   Note that `toArray(new Object[0])` is identical in function to `toArray()`.

Answer (score 4):

`toArray()` returns an `Object[]` [and not any object derived from `Object[]`]. Each element in this array is of type `Class`, but the array itself is not of type `Class[]`

You should cast each element in the array to `Class` instead of trying to cast the array, or use [Collection.toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) to avoid casting.

Answer (score 1):

Use  T[] toArray(T[] a) from [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for listing out the `values` of `map` i.e. class names:

```
Object[] array = map.values().toArray();
for (Object object : array) {
    System.out.println(object.toString());
}
```